# Is it possible to implement several IEnumerable<T> in one class?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I want to do something like this:

```
class T : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>
{
    string [] _strings = new string [20];
    int[] _ints = new int[20];

    public T() { }

    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (string str in _strings)
            yield return str;
    }

    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (int i in _ints)
            yield return i;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

}
//Using in code:
T t = new T();
foreach (int i in t)
   //to do something
foreach (string str in t)
   //to do stuff
```

I desire to know Is there a way to realize It or not. May be there are tricks ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've nearly managed to *implement* both interfaces - you just need to change the non-generic implementation to show which generic implementation you're trying to delegate to. For example:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<int>)this).GetEnumerator();
}
```

However, because you're implementing more than one `IEnumerable<T>` interface you'll need to cast in the foreach loop to show which one to use:

```
T t = new T();
foreach (int i in (IEnumerable<int>) t)
   //to do something
foreach (string str in (IEnumerable<string>) t)
```

Personally I would strongly advise *against* doing this if possible though - it'll cause a lot of confusion for people reading your code.

See section 8.8.4 of the C# language specification for details of how the compiler treats the expression to iterate over in a `foreach` loop.

(By using "normal" interface implementation for *one* of the interfaces you could provide a sort of "default" - but I don't think that would really make it any better.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest defining some struct types whose only field is an instance of your class type, initialized by the stuct's constructor, whose only public member would be GetEnumerator, and which implements IEnumerable<whatever> by calling an appropriate method on your base type.  Then have your root class implement a member that returns a new instance of an appropriate struct.

For example, if your class Foo had a GetStringEnumerator method which returned a type that implements IEnumerable<String>, you could have Foo.AsStrings return a struct FooStringEnumerable whose GetEnumerator method called Foo.GetStringEnumerator.

Note that by having your enumerable thing be a struct rather than a class, you would avoid having to create an extra object instance in the common case where it is used in a "for-each" loop, since both vb and c# would duck-type the GetEnumerator method instead of casting to IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>.